# Cloud ML Notebooks vs Cloud Datalab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

Can anyone please help me find the differences between these 2 google products?

1. [Cloud ML Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/notebooks/overview)
2. [Cloud Datalab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/)

In which cases should I use one or the other?

Thanks!